# Change/Remove post improvement notification when downvote Meta questions/answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[image]

I propose to remove this notice, because (as far as I know) on the meta, upvotes and downvotes literally mean that I am in favor of an idea/proposal/etc. or "against". Therefore, the notification with the vote "against" that "post can be improved" is absolutely meaningless for me

But I assume that this is most likely standard for all platforms, so they will not remove it. But if this cannot be removed, then at least you need to change the content to something more appropriate in meaning

For example, something like:

> Please leave a comment why you are against the proposed idea

It is clear that not only ideas are being discussed here, so it is not entirely correct, but in general I hope I conveyed the essence

Comment: Downvotes don't necessarily mean disagreement. The usual reasons (no research effort, unclear, not useful) can still be valid here.

Comment: I think this popup is perfectly innocent in any context. The key is the "consider [...] if you think the this post can be improved" part. If you cannot think of an improvement, **done**. If you consider commenting and decide against it, **done**. It's neither an obligation nor necessity to comment, nor does it mean that you cannot (consider to) comment due to other reasons.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't think so. Your answer is the example of how this notification can be interpreted. Of course it is not obligation but in this case there can be a notification like "Please consider editing post if you think ..." or "Please consider flag as 'needs improvement ' post if you think ..." and then you would say that "If you cannot edit post to improve **done**", "If you consider to flag question, **done**". The message of notification absolutely doesn't show the meaning of downvoting on Meta

Comment: @EzioMercer I'm challenging that the popup is "absolutely meaningless". In fact, IMO it is the most meaningful – downvotes *always* can mean content problems, whereas disagreement only applies to specific cases (and even then content problems can still apply too!). Editing and especially flagging are *much* more impactful actions and often should not be considered to begin with.

Comment: @Turamarth Yes you are right that usual reasons are still valid but as said in help "voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself"

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You are right but as said in help "voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself" so I think that the content problem is not the main reason to downvote on Meta

Comment: @EzioMercer That's just selective quoting. The help makes it pretty clear that this only partially applies to a subset of meta Q&A. ["Like normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta allows members to vote on questions and answers. **For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes.** \[…\] **On posts tagged feature-request**, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change **rather than just the quality or usefulness** of the post itself."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, and there is also said "For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness" of course post must be well-written, well-reasoned and well-searched. Obviously, if I make a post in which nothing is clear, I will get a lot of downvotes but if all conditions of good post are met then votes will display agreement or disagreement

Comment: IMO for a lot of meta posts, the downvote implies "Ugh, not this again!" :)

Comment: @EzioMercer the point is that an automated system cannot figure out what the user means by their downvote reliably (without asking the user) so giving them a generic option (the current one) is better than a specific "_Please leave a comment why you are against the proposed idea_"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I also don't like a specific reason. I give this example as something more acceptable for meta. I couldn't come up with a universal phrase. I very love the tooltip text "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". And I think that current one is also specific reason because I can downvote not only because of post needs improvements

Comment: @EzioMercer I'm not particular fond of how it is written, people do like to conveniently ignore the part after the semicolon. It is written in a way that invites people to just read it in whatever way supports their downvoting desire.

Answer (score 5):

You have the right idea, but not quite the right implementation.

**Let's get rid of this message entirely! Everywhere.**

We don't need to encourage people to leave any more comments—we get far more than enough as it is.

Comment: I will only be glad if this message does not exist in principle :)